# Spurious wake after suspend

Tags: suspend, resume, wakeonlan

I'm running Ubuntu 22.10 and have a problem that my machine does not want to stay suspended. It wakes up usually withing half hour of being put into suspend. Syslog clearly indicates that it's NetworkManager that handles it (the log says "wake requested" and it's coming from NetworkManager). The thing is that wake-on-LAN is disabled everywhere, in NetworkManager config, in the driver (or whatever you change by using "ethtool") and even in BIOS. Any ideas where to look is much appreciated.

Comment: As a test, unplug the network cable, suspend, wait 2 or 3 1/2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I resolved this issue by explicitly disabling wake-on-lan in NetworkManager config (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wake-on-LAN for how to do it). This of cause makes no sense as supposedly it was already disabled.